# How to delete everything afrer ":"

Tags: text-processing

I have lines like these:

```
name:surname
name2:surname2
```

I would like to delete everything after `:`

Comment: One way `awk -F : '{print $1}'`

Comment: how can I place them one behind other with , (coma) separated ? Tnx

Comment: paste -d, -g file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on his comment "how can I place them one behind other with , (coma) separated ?"

```
awk -F: '{printf("%s,",$1)}' input.txt
```

Comment: I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
sed -i 's/:.*$//g' $FILE
```

Comment: many many tnx I appreciate it

Comment: An explanation of what's going on there would improve this answer substantially.

Comment: Welcome. If helped,  mark question as answered and upvote the answer.
Thank you.

Comment: @ Michael Homer sure.
As per my understanding sed replaces matching pattern for ":.*$"  with [:blank:] 
":.*$" : match pattern from ":" to end of the line

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
$ cat file
name:surname
name2:surname2
$ cat file | cut -d: -f1
name
name2
```